# How can you make a transition from describing the past to describing the present in your narration?

Tags: phrase-request

When talking about the past, can I say "fast forward to 2020, [...]" and then continue by describing some modern events? If not, how can I say it differently? I want a transition that would be applicable both to the present and to the future in the past (something like 'In the 1930s, [...]. Fast forward to 1980, [...]').

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can say "fast forward" it is correct and has some idiomatic use.  There are very many ways to indicate this transition. I only mention the simplest:  "Now".

> In the 1980s our company was small and based entirely in Ireland. Now it has offices in twenty countries and employs 5000 people.

Comment: I want a transition that would be applicable both to the present and to the future in the past (something like 'In the 1930s, [...]. Fast forward to 1980, [...]')